# Eclipse project explorer expand on startup

Tags: eclipse, startup

Is there a way to get Eclipse to save the state of the project explorer tree and expand to where it was on startup?  Every time I shut down Eclipse and start it back up, the file I had open last is opened, but the tree in the project explorer is completely collapsed...

Comment: +1 great question, this has been bugging me for years now and I never bothered to ask if there was a solution.

Comment: oh great, someone has dealt with this for years and hasn't found a solution.  I thought I just couldn't find it cause I'm new to Eclipse.  haha!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Found it!  If you click the "Link with Editor" (the button that has a left arrow over a right arrow) button in the Project Explorer, it expands the tree in the project explorer to the file you're currently editing.  This is a toggle button and its state is saved when closing Eclipse.  So when you open it back up, your project explorer is expanded to the file that is currently open.

Comment: Works in Eclipse 4.4.2.