# Save Aptana Studio 3 project explorer state on close

Tags: project, aptana, state

I'm sure there is a simple option for this but I have as yet been unable to find it. Every time I close and reopen Aptana Studio 3 it collapses all the folders in the project explorer and I have to reopen them all, is there a way to get it to leave them open and save the project explorer's state when I close the program?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the App Explorer rather than the Project Explorer and it will save its state.

Comment: @SarahKemp Thank you, does that mean it's not possible to save the state of the project explorer? If so, put that as a stackoverflow answer and I'll mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find any way to keep the state of the Project Explorer. However, using the **App Explorer**, the state of your open folder will be preserved. You can also try the **"Navigator"** which looks just like the Project Explorer, but appears to keep state. I will add the proviso to that: It kept state when I restarted aptana, but it also developed a GUI glitch where it appears to be scrolled to the right so I only see the right half of all of my file names and I cannot fix it, so this may not be a good option if you get the same glitch.

There is also a method which does not do quite what you ask, but may be a good fix for you anyway. If you click **"Link with Editor"** picture (two yellow arrows) in the Project Editor, it will automatically expand your project hierarchy to match whichever open file you have active. Since your files stay open when you close Aptana, this would keep the Project Explorer expanded to whatever you are looking at even on restart. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651791/eclipse-project-explorer-expand-on-startup)

You can also set up **working sets** for various parts of your code that are buried in the hierarchy and use the Project Explorer to show those working sets instead of you projects. This does not save state, but it does give you easy access to common parts of your code that may be deeply buried.

Hope one of these helps you.