# Is there way to automatically expand a specific folder in Eclipse Project Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, expand, project-explorer

I would like to have a certain folder in the Project Explorer expand automatically upon opening the project (or starting Eclipse with the project already open).

When working on multiple projects, you find yourself closing and opening projects a lot, and closing all relevant editors (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `w`), so the [editor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651791/eclipse-project-explorer-expand-on-startup) as commented by Torsten is not the solution I am looking for.

Pressing asterisc (`*`) expands all folders. However, I would like this (1) to happen automatically, and more importantly (2) only expand a certain (sub)folder.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, as long as you can live with an open editor in your workspace. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651791/eclipse-project-explorer-expand-on-startup

Comment: This solution only works when the project is already open and being edited (before Eclipse was closed).

Answer (score 0):

Try `Shift+numpad_multiply` for exapanding every file under a package/folder and `Ctrl+Shift+numpad_divide` for collapsing a project. I think this works better on Navigator for a big project because when I tried it in my project explorer, I ended up crashing eclipse.